How to implement Push Notifications which come from FCM directly to web in a React Native WebView App
I have a nextjs webapp, it has FCM web push notifications, for the same I have a react native webview wrapper basically, how do I make it such that the push notifications coming up, display as app notifications.
I tried regularly implementing FCM in my app altogether but I do not want that

For this, One option we have is to setup listeners for notification in your web app and further, you have to send the payload from notification listener to web-view with window.postMessage method.
